# Dictionary get nil

Tags: ios, swift

what is wrong with xcode? Get nil for key 9.0

```swift
  @IBAction func sliderAction(_ sender: UISlider) {
        speed = round(sender.value / step) * step
        sender.value = speed
        speedLabel.text = modeDict[sender.value]
        print(sender.value)
        print(speedLabel.text)
    }

    let modeDict : [Float : String] = [ 0.8 : "Pls delete game, you noob", 0.9 : "Pff, girl", 1.0 : "Optimal", 1.1 : "Very Hard", 1.2 : "Almost Unreal"]
    let step : Float = 0.1
    var speed : Float = 0.0

    //
```

**Print** so, why 9.0 -> nil ?

0.8
Optional("Pls delete game, you noob")

**0.9
nil**

1.0
Optional("Optimal")

1.1
Optional("Very Hard")

1.2
Optional("Almost Unreal")

Comment: `why 9.0 -> nil`....9.0 or 0.9 ?

Comment: `Float` is a binary floating point number and *cannot* represent the value `0.9` exactly. Using Float or Double as dictionary keys is therefore problematic.

Comment: Try `print(modeDict)` and you'll see `..., 0.899999976: "Pff", ...`

Comment: maybe it helps you (despite its for python, the approach is similar)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23721230/float-values-as-dictionary-key

Comment: @MartinR , thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to shift keys by 10

```
let modeDict : [Float : String] = [ 8 : "Pls delete game, you noob", 9 : "Pff, girl", 10 : "Optimal", 11 : "Very Hard", 12 : "Almost Unreal"]
```

and use

```
speedLabel.text = modeDict[sender.value*10]
```