# Zip lists by function output in Python

Tags: python, list, python-itertools, python-zip

It is known that if we have two lists in python `l1` and `l2`, one can use `zip(l1, l2)` in order to create a list of tuples from both `l1` and `l2`.

Now, lets assume that we have two functions `f1` and `f2`. I would like to create a list of tuples  with elements from `l1` and `l2` (like the `zip` output) such that the output of `f1` on the element from `l1` will be equal to the output of `f2` on the element from `l2`. In mathematic form:

[image]

In my use case, one can assume that `f1` and `f2` are both **injective functions**. But, it is not guaranteed that every element of `l1` has a match in `l2` and vise versa.

Here's a code that does that:

```py
from itetools import product

tuples_list = [
    (e1, e2)
    for e1, e2 in product(l1, l2)
    if f1(e1) == f2(e2)
]
```

I wonder if there's a better way of doing it (maybe it's already implemented in a built-in library in a faster/cleaner way).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider that [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is in essence a wrapper for a nested loop. So a solution which doesn't require external modules would be:

```py
tuples_list = [
    (e1, e2)
    for e1 in l1
    for e2 in l2
    if f1(e1) == f2(e2)
]
```

However, this solution can still be optimized. Since you resort to the cartesian product, this means you are re-calculating the `f1` and `f2` functions various times for each of the input values, which means you are adding needless complexity. You could cache the output values of the functions, my solution for a faster solution is:

```py
lf1 = [f1(v) for v in l1]
lf2 = [f2(v) for v in l2]

tuples_list = [
    (l1[i1], l2[i2])
    for i1, fe1 in enumerate(lf1)
    for i2, fe2 in enumerate(lf2)
    if fe1 == fe2
]
```

Answer (score 2):

If your functions are expensive to compute you might want to precompute f1 and f2 before doing the product. Instead of computing the functions NxM times you can compute them N+M times. You could do

```
l1_out = [(f1(el_l1), el_l1) for el_l1 in l1]
l2_out = [(f1(el_l2), el_l2) for el_l2 in l2]

tuples_list = [(x[1], y[1]) for x in l1_out for y in l2_out if x[0] == y[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the solutions posted by Rui Reis and SMeznaric and they inspired me to write my own.

My solution is less intuitive, but I think it works faster.

**Code:**

```
def find_pairs(l1, l2, f1, f2):
    d = {}
    for e1 in l1:
        d[f1(e1)] = e1

    tuples_list = []
    for e2 in l2:
        if f2(e2) in d:
            tuples_list.append((d[f2(e2)], e2))

    return tuples_list
```

---

**Explanation**:

1. Create an empty dictionary.
2. Fill the dictionary with [f1, e1] pairs. That is, for every element *e1* in list *l1*, compute the value of the function *f1*. That value (*f1*) will be the key for the dictionary, and the element itself (*e1*) will be the value. Note that this only requires **one** pass through the first list.
3. **(Crucial part)** Now, we pass through list *l2*. For every element *e2* in list *l2*, we compute the value of the function *f2*. Now we check whether this computed function value already exists in our dictionary. This operation is **O(1)** fast! (https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). If the value already exists in the dictionary, that means that we
   have a case that *f1(e1) == f2(e2)*. We only don't know what *e1*
   is. But, since we cached it in the dictionary as the correspoding
   key-value pair, we get *e1* by getting the value from the dictionary
   under key *f1*. And we know *f1*, since *f1 == f2(e2)*. So:
   *d[f2(e2)] == e1*.

---

**Notes**:

- This should be quite fast since *f1* is applied only once on every element of *l1*, and *f2* is applied only once on every element of *f2*.
- In the actual code provided, f2(e2) is computed *twice*. I did this for readability, but we can easily memorise f2(e2) into a variable.
- The speed-up relies on storing the function values as keys in a dictionary, so that time isn't spent searching for matches.
- If *f1* and *f2* are real functions (return floats), they can still be used as dictionary keys: [Float values as dictionary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23721230/float-values-as-dictionary-key)

Comment: Hey @waykiki, thanks for the answer!
Pay attention that your solution would not work if the output of `f1` and `f2` is not hashable, since you use it as a dictionary key.

Comment: @SagiShadur Yeah, you're absolutely right. However, I thought of just posting this answer because most functions probably do return hashable objects (such as an integer/float). The answers above provide good optimization and do not require the functions to return hashable objects :-)